# What's in the alpha channel in jp2 imagery file downloaded from usgs?

Tags: usgs, jpeg-2000

I'd like to know what's in the 4th channel in jp2, imagery files downloaded from USGS. In Photoshop those files open in grayscale mode, so to fix it I change them to multichannel and then RGB. But I assume it doesn't matter. From the beginning file contain 4 channels. RGB + something...

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What image are you downloading? Do you have a link?

Comment: Add links to all metadata that you find about USGS imagery. Read the links yourself first.

Comment: I pick an area and then DL any imagery I can get. I have 2 sections there: NAIP and HRO, so it's from one of them. Description says nothing I guess, example:  https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/58282427e4b01fad870f9744

Comment: There is a link to https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/file/get/58282427e4b01fad870f9744?f=__disk__8e%2Ffb%2Fff%2F8efbff0bca801f58c2358c9b4a67a633a375baf4&transform=1&allowOpen=true and you will find the answer from there.

Comment: OK, cool, so it's RGBIR- Infrared.